# C++ Application using TCL API to enable package autoloading

Tags: c++, tcl, tcl-api

I want to have my C++ application to enable package autoloading for all ActiveTcl packages in `C:\Tcl\lib`. I pass below tcl command to `Tcl_Eval()` in my C++ code. And expect "`package require <package name>`" will automatically find the package and load it.

```
set ::auto_path [file join {C:\Tcl\lib}]
```

But it didn't work as what it does in TCL shell - TCL shell looks for `pkgIndex.tcl` in auto_path, so when "`package require`", it can find the right package or shared libs. Is it possible to make it work in C++ application? Or is there any better way?

Comment: Did you initialize the Tcl interpreter correctly? Especially a call to `Tcl_FindExecutable()` http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/FindExec.htm

Comment: I did. Checking "info nameofexecutable" returns the right information.

Comment: By the way, $::auto_path is undefined in the Tcl interpreter in my application. Is that normal?

Comment: Usually it is defined when init.tcl is processed, so you seem to lack the script library initialization. Have a look at this thread, especially the answer by Don Porter: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/KdPdMzur5T4

Comment: It's working now. By setting $tcl_library and call Tcl_Init to load init.tcl. Thanks @schlenk.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I know what the problem might be. The `auto_path` is a *Tcl list* of directories — the code that uses it iterates over the list with `foreach` — that are searched for packages (and auto-loaded scripts, an old mechanism that I think is rather more trouble than it's worth). Yet you're using a single element, the output of that `file join`. This wouldn't usually matter on platforms other than Windows, as the directory separator is `/` there (and that's just an ordinary non-whitespace character to Tcl) but on Windows the directory separator is `\` and that's a list metasyntax character to Tcl.

What does this mean? Well, after:

```
set ::auto_path [file join {C:\Tcl\lib}]
```

We can ask what the things of that *list* are. For example, we can print the first element of the list…

```
puts [lindex $::auto_path 0]
```

What does that output? Probably this:

```
C:Tcllib
```

OOooops! The backslashes have been taken as quoting characters, leaving an entirely non-functioning path. That won't work.

The fix is to use a different way to construct the `auto_path`. I think you'll find that this does what you actually want:

```
set ::auto_path [list {C:\Tcl\lib}]
```

Though this is an alternative (still using `list`; it's best for trouble-free list construction in all cases):

```
set ::auto_path [list [file normalize {C:\Tcl\lib}]]
```

(My bet is that you're trying to use `file join` as a ghetto `file normalize`. Don't do that. It's been poor practice for a long time now, especially now that we have a command that actually does do what you want.)

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to get you an answer. I must've just missed seeing your question when you asked it…